# Release Management and Dsc - How to queue a build when a release is in progress?

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I have VSO and Release Management 2013.4 working and deploying to Azure vm's via DSC

The build profile is set to trigger on commit to the Git repo and the release template is set to be triggered on successful build from TFS

However if a developer commits in quick succession the resultant builds cause releases to overlap in RM? - this causes some of the releases to fail with a DSC error ("the consistency check or pull cmdlet is in progress....")

Is there a way to force RM to prevent concurrent releases?  (based on the same release template and build profile)

Comment: Is it your intention / desire to do a release on every commit?

Comment: yes - at least to the integration test stage - from there I may use RM manual approval to propagate to later stages in the pipeline

Comment: Thought I'd check because one of the applications I work with takes an hour to build and four hours to run all the automated web tests. Releasing on every commit is impossible and instead we have a checkin build definition that does CI and runs unit tests and a separate build definition that runs on a schedule each night and after CI and running unit tests deploys the app so the automated tests can run overnight. Can you clarify what you mean by 'test stage'? Do you mean unit tests (which should just run on the build agent server) or other tests which require your app to be deployed?

Comment: our test stage might be referred to as an integration test stage - we have a unit test suite that does run as part of the TFS build on the build agent but previously we used Jenkins to create a deployment pipeline that would then deploy the software onto a test server (dogfooding the deployment package in the process) and run longer running tests eg - browser automation via selenium  - its this pipeline I'm trying to replicate in RM - I wanted to keep the initial tfs build under 10mins so that devs get feedback that code compiles and tests pass - ie safe to pull changes

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at my blog post series on [Continuous Delivery with TFS](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs/).

Comment: Another thought - does a build definition configured for Git have Rolling builds or Gated Check-in options?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that - switched to gated check-in to see if that makes a diff - suspect its still possible to cause 2 releases to be triggered if release takes longer than build (which is likely if it involves manual steps or long running tests)